# Java how to Compare last 4 strings

Tags: java

I am preparing for my exam and was wondering if anyone can give me an idea how to compare 2 strings if the final 4 characters using `substring` returns true and false if length is  less than 4 for either of the strings.

I am trying

```
table.substring(0,4).equals(table);
    return true;
if (table.length() <4)
return false;
```

Comment: Have you tried out java syntax? This is far from being java code - neither do the quotation marks match, nor is your table.length() in an if statement...  If you want to check if the String starts with the **5** letter of the word "table", you should use `myString.startsWith("table")` - if your talking about the *last* characters, you can use `myString.endsWith("table")`. `substring(0,4)` returns a 4 letter substring - starting from idx 0 (inclusive) to 4 (exclusive). Please read the API Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Thanks for replying. The question wants me to use substring and the equals to find the answer. I need to give them what they ask. so using substring to return true four final characters and if the length of either string is less than 4 return false. That's one of the past exam papers. It will be a written test

Comment: so use `.stubstring(0,5)`! But you haven't answered yet. You said "final 4 characters" should the word start or end with "table"? "Table" has 5 letters! 1: t, 2: a, 3: b, 4: l, 5: e

Comment: it starts from the end so should only be able not table

Comment: Look at @Matthew's answer - it shows how to simulate `.endsWith()` with `.substring()' - I guess that's what you want also your question is not really clear (or just poor English)

Comment: It is not yet clear what your task is – are you trying to say you have to write a method taking two strings and returning true if and only if both of them have length at least 4 and they match in the last 4 positions? It would help if your sample code were a complete method; as it stands, it only operates on one string, called ‘`table`’ and can fall through without returning a result!

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used table, yes basically s1 and s2 if length less than 4 return false -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid your code to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you must check the lenght of the string first.

```
boolean result = false;
if (table.length() >= 4) {
    int length = table.length();
    result = table.substring(length - 4, length).equals("table");
}
return result;
```

Otherwise, you can try to have a look at the [`endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) method of the `String` class.

Try to avoid multiple `return` statements inside a single method, also if the method is small. Having a single return point lets you managed the functional flow in a better way.

Comment: Single return point also means you are sure to hit a breakpoint on it in your debugger, unless an exception is thrown, which is useful too.

Comment: Could you accept the answer or at least upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will get the first 4 characters of the string.

the substring method takes two parameters (beginningIndex, Ending index)

you are saying that you want the characters from index 0 (the beginning of the string) to 4 characters after that. You also have quotes where they shouldn't be

Let's use an example:

String myString = "HelloWorld";
myString.substring(0,4); - this will return "Hell"

IF you want the last 4 characters to work on any string you want to do something like: EDIT: added length check

```
    String myString = "HelloWorld";
    boolean match = false;
      if (myString.length() >=4){ 
       if(myString.substring(myString.length()-4,myString.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("orld")
          match = true;
      }
    return match;
```

What you are doing here is getting the substring from the end of the string (myString.length()) minus 4, all of the way to the end of the string(myString.length()) and checking to see if it equals what you expect it to "orld"

assigning true to a variable that you declared outside of the if statement (I named it match which defaults to false) then you are returning that boolean.

Comment: yes. This will work on a string of any length :-). Good luck on your exam. Let me know if you need any more help. Don't forget to approve my answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: Thank you :-) think I will need plenty more help haha